# Troubleshooting circuit design for sensor input and desired output range

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, circuit-design, analog, ltspice

[image]

[image]

I designed a circuit to process input from a sensor with a range of -300 mV to 300 mV. The desired output of the circuit is 0 V to 600 mV. To achieve this, I used the op-amp equation Vout = Vin + 0.3 as a basis for my design. However, when I simulated the circuit, the output was only around 900 mV.

I am seeking advice on where I may have made a mistake in my design. Can someone help me troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: What is the difference between the schematics. I thought they were the same.

Comment: Use the simple one op-amp design given as an answer in your prior question.  Your design above does not match that either. Add bipolar supplies (+ and -) to the op-amp.

Comment: I tried the first one with the -0.3V input voltage. This one above is similar to that one except this one doesn't have any resistors and gets Vref from the voltage divider.

Comment: I did everything you said and still output voltage didn't change, Can this be related to the opamps model? If it is how can I fix it?

Comment: Use this example as a guide for a proper op-amp subtraction circuit. https://www.eeeguide.com/subtractor-using-op-amp-or-difference-amplifier-circuit/

Comment: If you use a subtraction design your offset reference needs to be negative (-Vref).  If you want to use a positive Vref use an adder circuit, as shown here: https://masteringelectronicsdesign.com/the-transfer-function-of-the-summing-amplifier-with-n-input-signals/

Comment: In an actual adder circuit design if your Vref or sensor input is not a low impedance then you would need to buffer it with an additional op-amp (voltage follower), similar to the more complex answer in your older question.  [That is all for now there are already too many comments. here.]